# v-html content not being rendered correctly

Tags: html, vue.js

v-html content not being rendered correctly, altohught when I remove v-html in first li it works fine.

Here's my code.

```
<div>

  <br>
  <li v-html="`a`">
    <ul>
      <li v-html="`c`"> b </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <br>

</div>
```

why 'c' nor 'b' are not being rendered, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not valid HTML.

Comment: First why do you have ` ` (backticks) around `a` and `c`. Second `b` is printed on page.

Comment: ` ` cause v-html takes a variable no ? Also am testing in https://bootstrap-vue.org/play and b is not printed for me. - thanks for your answser

Answer (score 1):

v-html renders some given HTML as the **content** of the tag the v-html directive is used on.  You can't use both v-html and child elements and have them work together, the v-html in this instance overrides the child elements.

Answer (score 1):

`v-html` basically said - *keep this element's inner HTML up-to-date with the rawHtml property on the current active instance.*

Hence, The contents of the `li` will be replaced with the value of the rawHtml property passed in the `v-html`. That's the reason you are not able to see the inner HTML content of `li`.

Also, No need to use backticks as `v-html` is a predefined directive by Vue and it will accept the property as a rawHtml.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    a: '<ul>Render outer li Html</ul>',
    c: '<ul>Render inner li Html</ul>'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <li v-html="a">
    <ul>
      <li v-html="c">b</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```